# How to install grunt in windows globally?

Tags: gruntjs

```
Windows :npm install -g grunt-cli
Windows :npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save-dev
Windows :grunt
grunt command not found
```

How to install grunt locally and globally on windows system.

Comment: How about registering the path to grunt in the windows environment variables?

Comment: I have given envoirement variable path :C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\

Comment: still same error :- grunt command not found

Comment: This one should work though C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt\bin

Comment: Yeah,this work for me

Answer (score 1):

In windows we need to register the path in the windows environment variables:-

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\npm

Close and open terminal(cmd,git-bash,etc)
```